# Excel formula containing double quotes through VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

```
Range("D2").Formula = "=IF(C2>0,HYPERLINK(\\\Haroon-pc\d\DatabaseCNIC\"&C2&".png",C2),"")"
```

my excel formula has ampersand, slashes. quotes etc. How to set *Range("D2").Formula"* with above formula.

Please someone write it for me in proper format.

Comment: In vba to use a `""`, one must use `""""`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub qwerty()
   Range("D2").Formula = "=IF(C2>0,HYPERLINK(""\\\Haroon-pc\d\DatabaseCNIC\.png"",C2),"""")"
End Sub
```